# mySQLi query: why I have no results?

Tags: php, mysqli, size

When I do the same query from phpMyAdmin I have results as we can see of the picture of the link:
http://i59.tinypic.com/ncd2mp.jpg

But when I do the same from php the size of the query is 0:

```
<?php   
//Connect to Database 
$con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","","moodle2"); 

//Check connection 
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { 
    echo 'Database connection error: ' . mysqli_connect_error(); 
    exit(); 
} 

//Escape special characters to avoid SQL injection attacks 
$namesubject="Aplicaciones Telemáticas Multimedia (Telemática)";
$namecategory="HTML CSS JS";
$namesubject=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$namesubject);
$namecategory=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$namecategory);

//Query the database to get the user details. 
$query="SELECT id, preguntaid, nombrepregunta, textopregunta, tipopregunta, categorianum FROM mdl_eliza_preguntas WHERE categorianum = (SELECT id FROM mdl_eliza_categoria WHERE namecategoria = '".$namesubject."' AND courseid = (SELECT category FROM mdl_course WHERE fullname = '".$namecategory."')) ORDER BY id";
$userdetails = mysqli_query($con,$query); 
//If no data was returned, check for any SQL errors 
if (!$userdetails) { 
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysqli_error($con); 
    exit; 
} 

$size=mysqli_num_rows($userdetails);        
?>
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

As per [**your originally posted question**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26377779/1) where you've changed `'".$namecategory".'` to `'".$namecategory."'` after my answer was posted:

---

Change:

```
WHERE fullname = '".$namecategory".')) ORDER BY id";
```

to:

```
WHERE fullname = '".$namecategory."')) ORDER BY id";
```

You have misplaced the quote/dot.

This seems to be the most likely cause as to why your query failed.

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 Thanks, I'm next to 100% sure that's where the error is caused by.

Comment: The error still happens, even if I change the variables to the real name of the subject and the category.

Comment: @user3738027 Can you tell me what the error is, is it an error message?

Comment: There is no error message. I have 0 rows as result.

Comment: @user3738027 You're not doing anything with `$size=mysqli_num_rows($userdetails);` are you not using it and relying on it?

Comment: Yes, I am doing more things, but my problem is that the query size is 0 so I have simplified the code.

Comment: @user3738027 Ah ok. Well if you're getting a `0` and the query did not throw an error, then this tells me that either your query is incorrectly structured, or it's not matching the criteria you've given it. You may need to use a JOIN for this, which is something I'm not very good at to tell you the truth.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I think that it is well structured because I do the same query from phpMyAdmin and I obtain the data

Comment: @user3738027 Is this the string you entered in phpMyadmin `SELECT id, preguntaid, nombrepregunta, textopregunta, tipopregunta, categorianum FROM mdl_eliza_preguntas WHERE categorianum = (SELECT id FROM mdl_eliza_categoria WHERE namecategoria = '".$namesubject."' AND courseid = (SELECT category FROM mdl_course WHERE fullname = '".$namecategory."')) ORDER BY id`?

Comment: Yes it is. Change the variables for concrete values. SELECT id, preguntaid, nombrepregunta, textopregunta, tipopregunta, categorianum FROM mdl_eliza_preguntas WHERE categorianum = (SELECT id FROM mdl_eliza_categoria WHERE namecategoria = 'HTML CSS JS' AND courseid = (SELECT category FROM mdl_course WHERE fullname = 'Aplicaciones Telemáticas Multimedia (Telemática)')) ORDER BY id

Comment: @user3738027 I'm curious: `HTML CSS JS` are those 3 seperate categories by any chance, inside seperate rows?

Comment: No, HTML CSS JS is the name of a field in a table called "mdl_course" in the column called "namecategoria".

Comment: @user3738027 Then this `WHERE namecategoria = '".$namesubject."'` needs to be `WHERE namecategoria = '".$namecategory."'` as per `$namecategory="HTML CSS JS";` and you might want to check the `WHERE fullname = '".$namecategory."'` while you're at it.